# Dividir os dados do mongo em mais de uma pasta. Possível?

Tags: mongodb

Tenho o mongodb rodando em um disco primário de 500GB. Como a base começou a crescer muito, coloquei um disco slave de 1TB e mudei pra ele a pasta data. 
Sei que com o tempo, esse disco de 1TB também será pouco.

Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de colocar um terceiro disco e fazer com que o mongo também use-o pra guardar dados. Ou seja, na minha concepção o mongo usaria os discos 2 e 3 e dividiria a carga de dados entre eles.
Minha pergunta aos entendidos é: isso existe? É possível?

Já pesquisei sobre o conceito de sharding, e inclusive já o entendi. Mas no shardind, eu dividiria os dados entre duas máquinas, ou seja, entre duas instâncias do mongodb. É uma opção que tenho pra ser usada em último caso.

Mas antes de partir para o sharding, eu ainda gostaria de saber se é possível numa mesma instância dividir os dados entre duas pastas diferentes (que estarão em discos diferentes).

Agradeço qualquer informação à respeito.

Answer (score 0):

Há algumas formas de você fazer isto, caso queira utilizar sharding mas não disponha de uma nova maquina, você pode ter duas ou mais instancias do mongod rodando em uma mesma maquina, cada uma com um dbpath diferente. Ou então você  pode ativar a opção storage.directoryPerDB, que fará com que cada banco de dados tenha seu próprio subdiretório dentro do caminho dbpath e fazer a montagem dos diretórios apontando para suas unidades em disco.

Mais informações em:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB

Comment: Pensei outra possibilidade: usar a opção directoryPerDB e ter as databases e pastas separadas. Dai eu moveria as pastas de algumas databases para outro disco e dentro da DB eu criaria atalhos, apontando pras pastas reais que estarão no outro disco. Pode dar certo?

Comment: Sinceramente eu não sei, nunca testei essa solução, mas acho que vale a pena a tentativa.